# Time Capsule showing backups date in pink

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I have tried a lot of net to find, why does time machine shows pink icons of the date. But not a solid answer i have found. I don't have a new computer, as i heard when you change hard disk. The Time Capsule understand it as old one. But yesterday i needed some backup and found out for last 2 months, every date in pink. Why is that? How can i assure that every backup of mine is backup which i can rely on?, and not pink.

Answer (score 1):

- Local snapshots (stored on your internal drive) are white.
- Backups stored on your Time Machine disk are pink.

The pink backups are correct as they are your real backups. Local snapshots are meant as temporary, intermediate backups and will be deleted automatically.

> Local Snapshots appear in the "Star Wars" display much like normal Time Machine backups.  The main difference is they're shown in white/gray in the Timeline, not the purple of a Time Machine backup on an external volume.
>
> Like normal Time Machine backups, Local Snapshots are usually made hourly.   If your Time Machine volume is available, both are usually done at the same time, so you'll see adjacent purple and white tick marks with the same time.  If the Time Machine volume isn't available, Local snapshots will continue on the same schedule, so for that period you'll only see white ones.
>
> Also, the "contextual menu" you get on Local Snapshots doesn't allow deleting a Snapshot, or all Snapshots of selected items, as on normal backups.

Comment: but the pink icons aren't clickable. What should I do? How do I verify the proper backup as pink aren't clickable

Comment: @Nofel Make sure your backup disk is connected and mounted